# Reading a dataframe after converting to csv file renders incorrect dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write the below dataframe into a csv file:

`df`:

```
    +--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+------------+
|               title|UserData.UserValue._title|UserData.UserValue._valueRef|UserData.UserValue._valuegiven|UserData._idUser|  _id|              author|         description|   genre|price|publish_date|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+------------+
|XML Developer's G...|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                           qwe|              18|bk101|Gambardella, Matthew|An in-depth look ...|Computer|44.95|  2000-10-01|
|       Midnight Rain|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                        dfdfrt|              19|bk102|          Ralls, Kim|A former architec...| Fantasy| 5.95|  2000-12-16|
|     Maeve Ascendant|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                          dfdf|              20|bk103|         Corets, Eva|After the collaps...| Fantasy| 5.95|  2000-11-17|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+------------+
```

I am using this code to write to a csv file:

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("hdfsOut")
```

Using this, it creates 3 different `csv` files in the folder `hdfsOut`. When I trying to read that dataframe using

```
var csvdf = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("header", true).csv("hdfsOut")
csvdf.show()
```

it displays the dataframe in incorrect form like this:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+------------+
|               title|UserData.UserValue._title|UserData.UserValue._valueRef|UserData.UserValue._valuegiven|UserData._idUser|  _id|              author|         description|genre|price|publish_date|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+------------+
|     Maeve Ascendant|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                          dfdf|              20|bk103|         Corets, Eva|After the collaps...| null| null|        null|
|      society in ...|      the young surviv...|                        null|                          null|            null| null|                null|                null| null| null|        null|
|      foundation ...|                  Fantasy|                        5.95|                    2000-11-17|            null| null|                null|                null| null| null|        null|
|       Midnight Rain|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                        dfdfrt|              19|bk102|          Ralls, Kim|A former architec...| null| null|        null|
|      an evil sor...|      and her own chil...|                        null|                          null|            null| null|                null|                null| null| null|        null|
|      of the world."|                  Fantasy|                        5.95|                    2000-12-16|            null| null|                null|                null| null| null|        null|
|XML Developer's G...|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                           qwe|              18|bk101|Gambardella, Matthew|An in-depth look ...| null| null|        null|
|         with XML...|                 Computer|                       44.95|                    2000-10-01|            null| null|                null|                null| null| null|        null|
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-----+-----+------------+
```

I need this `csv` file in order to feed it to Amazon Athena. When I do this, Athena also renders the data in same format as shown in the second output. Ideally, it should show me only 3 rows after reading it from converted `csv` file.

Any idea why this is happening and how can I resolve this issue to render the csv data in its correct form as shown in the first output?

Comment: what's are the characters immediately before "society in" and "foundation" etc before written to csv?

Comment: These are basically content inside a description heading like this:
`After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data in `description` column should have data with `new line characters` and `commas` as below

```
"After the collapse of a nanotechnology \nsociety in England, the young survivors lay the \nfoundation for a new society"
```

so for test purpose I created a dataframe as

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Maeve Ascendant", "_CONFIG_CONTEXT", "#id13", "dfdf", "20", "bk103", "Corets, Eva", "After the collapse of a nanotechnology \nsociety in England, the young survivors lay the \nfoundation for a new society", "Fantasy", "5.95", "2000-11-17")
).toDF("title", "UserData.UserValue._title", "UserData.UserValue._valueRef", "UserData.UserValue._valuegiven", "UserData._idUser", "_id", "author", "description", "genre", "price", "publish_date")
```

`df.show()` showed me the same dataframe format as you have in your question

```
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+-------+-----+------------+
|          title|UserData.UserValue._title|UserData.UserValue._valueRef|UserData.UserValue._valuegiven|UserData._idUser|  _id|     author|         description|  genre|price|publish_date|
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+-------+-----+------------+
|Maeve Ascendant|          _CONFIG_CONTEXT|                       #id13|                          dfdf|              20|bk103|Corets, Eva|After the collaps...|Fantasy| 5.95|  2000-11-17|
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+-------+-----+------------+
```

But `df.show(false)` gave the exact values as

```
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----+------------+
|title          |UserData.UserValue._title|UserData.UserValue._valueRef|UserData.UserValue._valuegiven|UserData._idUser|_id  |author     |description                                                                                                          |genre  |price|publish_date|
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----+------------+
|Maeve Ascendant|_CONFIG_CONTEXT          |#id13                       |dfdf                          |20              |bk103|Corets, Eva|After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
society in England, the young survivors lay the 
foundation for a new society|Fantasy|5.95 |2000-11-17  |
+---------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----+------------+
```

And when you saved it as csv, *spark saves it as text file with line feed and comma to be treated as simple text csv file*. And in csv format, *line feed generates a new line and comma generates a new field*. **Thats the culprit format in your data.**

## Solution 1

you can use *parquet* format to save the dataframe as *parquet saves the properties of a dataframe* and read it as *parquet* as

```
df.write.parquet("hdfsOut")
var csvdf = spark.read.parquet("hdfsOut")
```

## Solution 2

save it as csv format and use `multiLine` option while reading it

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("hdfsOut")
var csvdf = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("multiLine", "true").option("header", true).csv("hdfsOut")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it was the data thar wasn't in correct format and was having newline character. Marked as accepted.